# How to inject service to regular class in angular

Tags: angular, class, dependency-injection

So I'm trying to find a way to create a class with some services injection.

```
import {inject} from '@angular/core';

export class ModelStructure {
    dataService: DataService;

    constructor(type: number, form_id?: number) {
        this.dataService = inject(DataService);        
    }
}
```

However it doesn't seems to work and I'm getting the following error: https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

If I'm adding the following decorator:

```
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})
```

I'm getting another error about the constructor params
"This type is not supported as injection token."

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to make DataService available to ModelStructure, you would need to do:

```js
// data.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService { ... }


// model-structure.ts

export class ModelStructure {
  constructor(
    private readonly dataService: DataService,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. My "DataService" class is already injectable.
I would like to create new instance of `ModelStructure` class with some params, but also inject the "DataService" to it

For example:
```new ModelStructure(12)```

Comment: You don't need DI for that. Just new up an instance of the DataService in the constructor of ModelStructure